# How do you Add a delay between user press on imageButton?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I would like to make it so that the user has to wait a short time before allowed to press the imageButton, I don't know the best approach for this.

```
private class HandleClick implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks1);
            /* Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=1");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);*/
            simpleWebView.loadUrl("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=1");
            //startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if (arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton1){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks2);
            /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=2");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            //startActivity(intent);*/
            simpleWebView.loadUrl("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=2");
        }
        else if (arg0.getId()==R.id.imageButton2){
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5)).setText("Pressed: " + ++howManyClicks3);
            /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=3");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            //startActivity(intent);*/
            simpleWebView.loadUrl("https://abr.se/happyeno/?get=happyeno_svar_put&svar_id=3");

        }
    }
}
```

I don't want the user to be able to spam click the imageButtons. Maybe the best approach is to add a delay or disable the button for a short time after a it has been pressed?

Comment: after clicking a button wait for 5 sec after that your required task perform -this is want you want right

Comment: @MurugananthamS yes that might be the best way to approach it.

Comment: ok i will refer countdown timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try countdown timer inside your click listener

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      //count down 5,4,3,2,1.
   }

   public void onFinish() {
      //Write you logic here
   }

}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Magic here
        }
    }, 1000); // Millisecond 1000 = 1 sec
```

or you can have a look at [this Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)

Answer (score 0):

It will set OnClickListener after 5 seconds. You can also set OnClickListener immediately, then set image as enabled.

```
void setListeners() {
    imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);
    //or like that
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }, 5 * 1000);
}
```